# Comparing foreign keys

Tags: python, django

I am trying to compare two fields which are the same foreign key from a specific table.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from probes.models import Probe,Employee

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Schedules emails'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        to_list=[settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        for probj in Probe.objects.all():
            if probj.isExpired():
                empobj=Employee.objects.get(clientID==probj.clientID)
                to_list.append(empobj.email)
```

The console is raising a NameError: name 'clientID' is not defined.
Am I missing something here?

Employee class:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField("Employee Name",max_length=50,blank=False)
    email=models.CharField("Employee Email",max_length=50,blank=True)
    clientID=models.ForeignKey(Organisation)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of the `employee` class ?
Note also that class names should use the CapWords convention (see [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)) so here it should be `Probe` and `Employee`.

Comment: @Xebax, kindly see edited code

Comment: And `clientID` should be `client_id`.

Comment: Please add code for `Probe` model.

Answer (score 1):

In your code it should be `clientID=probj.clientID` and not `==`.

In your question you say "Comparing foreign keys" but it isn't a comparison here, it's a query with a condition "where clientID equals to probe's clientID".